# How to use multi layout in the same activity more efficient in android

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm building android application and i met some problems, please help me to solve it. 
My problems are "how to make program with multi layout in the same activity". Because in my program, the footer and the header are not change when change activity. If i using startActivity(), the current activity screen will be animate to left side and the newer activity will appear. But both activity must have the same footer and header. And i must write two functions with the same code.

How to resolve it? and what's method to change a content of activity, not change footer and header.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html).
Having fragments it is really flexible to have the different layout in the same activity.

You can have one FragmentActivity and in that activity you can place diifferent fragments with different layout in different time. All the transactions are made bu the fragment manager.

you can show , hide and replace individual fragments.

In your case you will have one fragment activity with a header and footer, and in between one placeholder for fragments. Then you will only change the fragments, you will not need to start new activity. Read about the fragments they will help you a lot with this kinds of scenarios.

Comment: Thank you, I just read it. but i'm build my app in hand phone, not tablet. I think fragment is suitable with tablet more. Do you have any idea to resolve it? Thanks.

Comment: you have a library you need to include , http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/fragments-for-all.html

Answer (score 0):

For my app, I created a header control that extends `LinearLayout.

```
public class TitleBar extends LinearLayout {
    public TitleBar(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public TitleBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.control_title_bar, this);
    }
```

This made a control I can include into several Activity screens.  To include, I just need to add the line into my XML layout:

```
<myapp.ui.TitleBar style="@style/FullWidth" android:id="@+id/titleBar" />
```

You could do a similar thing with a footer.

Comment: Thanks, i can use <merge></merge> tag. The same of your opinion. But when i change activity, i want only content of them change, footer and header (layout and action) is not change. you have 2 activities and from activity 1 change to activity 2. you will see animation animate from left to right and all screen will bi animate. i want only content of activity 2 appear. not is all screen of activity 2.

Comment: Sounds like @Lukap has the right idea with Fragments.  I've not had the chance to play with Fragments yet so cannot comment.  Be sure to mention if/how you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I strongly suggest you modify the app navigation design. As multiple activites is the android way of doing things. By using the android compatibility library you can use fragment with android phones.

Another way would be to use the android viewflipper which only shows one child at a time. You can also specify in and out animations for its child views. You will need to overide the onBackPressed method to make the back button work.

Comment: Thanks. But when the app change another activity, i want header and footer of current activity will be not animated. So only content of current activity is change. For example, i have 2 activities is activity 1 and activity 2. In activity 1, i have a footer (have 2 buttons to call 2 activity 1 & 2), header(footer and header of activity 1 and activity 2 are the same) and the main content is button, textview,...And when i pressd button2 in footer to call activity2. how can i keep the footer and header not animated? Not using tab and setContentView of Visible, Gone layout. Do you have good idea?